# Form CSS issue. silverstripe userdefined form

Tags: html, css, forms, silverstripe

I am using silverstripe userdefinedform module and I have created a form using its default css . I want form label and input on the same line but dont know how can i do this one please guide me for the same.

Here is the css code.

---

### This stylesheet includes both generic form styles and additional form styles for the User   Defined Form Module.

```
/* GENERIC FORMS  */

 form {
max-width: 500px;
width: 50%;}

 div.field {
margin: 10px 0 15px;}


fieldset {
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

form label {
margin-bottom: 5px;}

form label.left {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form label.right {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #888;
}

form input.text,
form textarea,
form .textajaxuniquetext,   /* Not sure if this is used? */
form select {
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
padding: 6px 5px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #dad9d9;}

.ie7 form select { width: 400px; } /* fix for ie7's rendering of max-width property on select input */

form input.text:focus,
form textarea:focus,
form .textajaxuniquetext:focus,
form select:focus {
outline:none;}
form input[disabled], form textarea[disabled] {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
border: 1px solid #dad9d9;}
textarea {
resize: vertical; /* forces text area to be resized vertically only */}


/* Radio and Checkbox */
.field .checkbox, .field .radio {
float: left; 
width: 13px; 
height: 13px; 
margin-right: 6px; 
margin-top: 3px;
padding: 0;}
.checkbox label.right,
.radio label.right {
    float: left;
}


 /* Messages */
 form .message {
background-color: #fef4ba;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #e8c805;
border-radius: 3px;}

form .good {
    background-color: #ecf9d0;
    border-color: #8fbe00;
}
form .bad, form .required {
    background-color: #f9d0d0;
    border-color: #cf0000;
    color: #b80000;
}


/* ACTIONS */
.Actions {
margin-bottom: 20px;}

a.btn, button, input[type="submit"], .Actions .action {
    background: #b80000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
a.btn:hover, button, input[type="submit"]:hover, .Actions .action:hover {
    background: #C80000;
    color: #fff;
}
a.btn {
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a.btn:after {                     /* creates arrow in button */
    content: '\2192';
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.ie7 input.action {
    width: 0;                     /* IE table-cell margin fix */
    overflow: visible;
}
input.action[class] {             /* IE ignores [class] */
    width: auto;                  /* cancel margin fix for other browsers */
}

.ie7 .Actions .action {
    float: left;
}
.Actions:after {
    color: #B94A48;
    content: "* Indicates a required field";
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
#MemberLoginForm_LoginForm .Actions:after {
    display: none;
}


/* AREA SPECIFIC */
/* LOGIN and FORGOT PASSWORD */
#Remember {
    min-height: 20px;
}
#ForgotPassword {
    clear: left;
}
#MemberLoginForm_LostPasswordForm .Actions:after {
    display: none;
}

/* Search / Login */
.header form .middleColumn {
    /* float: none;
    width: 100% !important; */
}




 /* USER DEFINED USER FORM MODULE STYLES
  ----------------------------------------------- */

 /*Generic and mixed*/
.FormHeading {
clear: both;
padding-top: 15px;}
form .date .middleColumn input {
/*background: transparent url(../images/icons/your_icon_here.png) no-repeat scroll 90px 5px;*/
width: 114px;}
.Actions input.resetformaction {                  /* Clear button */
float: left;
background-color: #888;}
.Actions input.resetformaction:hover {            /* Clear button */
background-color: #aaa;}

/* Labels */
.checkbox label.right {
font-size: 13px;                            /* reset to default */
color: #333;                                /* reset to default */}
 form .requiredField label.left:after { /* pseudo element adds an asterisk to a required fields label */
color: #B94A48;
content: "*";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-left: 3px;}

 /* Radio / Checkbox */
 form .checkboxset ul,
 form .optionset ul {
margin: 0;}
form .checkboxset li,
form .optionset li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
form div.checkbox:after { /* clearfix */
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
form .checkbox .checkbox { clear: both; }

   /* Messages */
   span.message {
   margin: 10px 0;
   display: block;
max-width: 390px;
clear: left;}
div.holder-required {               /* This class needs to be changed - is used for both input and div */
/* background-color: #f9d0d0;
border: 1px solid #cf0000;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: -11px; */}
form input.holder-required {        /* This class needs to be changed - is used for    both input and div */
border: 1px solid #cf0000; }

/* Error messages */
input:invalid,
textarea:invalid {
border-radius: 1px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;}
.no-boxshadow input:invalid,
.no-boxshadow textarea:invalid {
background-color: #f0dddd}

/* To test - potentially not needed? */
.ss-uploadfield-item-info button{
margin-top: 4px !important;
float: left;}
 form .creditCardField input,
 form input.currency,
 form input.numeric {
width: 50px;}
form #DMYDate-month,
form #DMYDate-day {
width: 25px}




 /* Responsive form styles
 ----------------------------------------------- */

 @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { 

  /* To test - potentially not needed? */
.header form .middleColumn {
    float: none;
    width: 100% !important;
}
form label.left,
#MemberLoginForm_LoginForm label {
    margin-bottom: 8px
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
form {
    max-width: 100%;
}}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) { }
```

Here The form picture attached, text and input field should be in a single line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use jsfiddle or something like that

Answer (score 0):

smth like this should get you started. If you don't know what to do with it, just add it to the bottom of the file, otherwise tweak it to your needs.

```
div.field {
    display:table-row;
    padding:0 0 20px 0;
}
form label.left {
    display: table-cell;
    width:30%;
    min-width:120px;
    float:left;
}
#Form_Form .middleColumn {
    display:table-cell;
    width:70%;
}
```